# How we can say java Single Class extends from one Class, Java single Class not extends more than one Class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Everyone know about every Class in java should be extends from Objects Class.

Let me explain with example there are two classes A and B.

```
Class A extends B {
}
```

> Note: Every Class should inherited from Object class by default. So we
>   can say class A extends from two Classes One is 'Class B' and Second
>   is 'Class Object'.

I am confused about Object class extends of every class.

Comment: Nope. Class `A` extends class `B`, which might extend `Object`.

Comment: @Mena not **might**, but **does**

Comment: @Paul you don't know that, as class `B`'s source isn't in the question.

Comment: @Mena **every** class is an (probably) indirect subclass of `Object`. A class that doesn't extend from any other class **always** implicitly extends `Object`.

Comment: @AndyTurner duh. That doesn't mean class `B` is not extending another class. It's not in the question. Of course the top class is always `Object`. But when you say "something extends something else", the tacit agreement is you're talking about direct inheritance. Class `B` is not shown in the question, so we don't know whether it extends class `C`, etc. or "nothing", i.e. implicitly `Object`.

Comment: I have agreed with @Mena comments. But I am still confused.